# Line break on a bookmark in maps.me app

Tags: android, maps, line, break

I want to make a line break in a bookmark in Maps.ME app, imported via KML file.
when I import without making changes it looks like this:

[image: bookmark in the app]

I want a line break instead of where it shows 
I have tried:

/n

/r/n

```
Environment.NewLine
```

and all kind of XML line breaks:

```
`&#x13&#x10;` `&#13;&#10;` `&#xD;`
```

Please help.

Comment: this is the open source code for this app:
https://github.com/mapsme/omim

Comment: What platform or system is this for?

Comment: it is for Android